# Python programming - Output issue between each function call

Tags: python

```
def displayChar(d):
    if d.isalpha():
        print(d, "is a str")
    elif a.isdigit():
        if 'float' in str(type(eval(d))):
            print(d, "is a float")
        else:
            print(d, "is a int")
    else:
        print("Your input is not allowed")
    del d

a = input('Enter the first word : ')
b = input('Enter the second word : ')
displayChar(a)
displayChar(b)
```

Not got intended output saying

```
A is a str
1 is a int
```

instead of "1 is a int" received below output
can some explain me please ?

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Suresh/PycharmProjects/Examples/func1.py
Enter the first word : A
Enter the second word : 1
A is a str
Your input is not allowed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This is a question of implementation or debugging which is off topic on Programmers.SE.  This site focus on the conceptual design and architecture questions as described in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: `elif a.isdigit():` should be `elif d.isdigit():`

Answer (score 0):

In the function you are passing in a variable that you name `a`, but one of the tests in your code is testing against `d`.

Change this:

```
elif a.isdigit():
```

to this:

```
elif d.isdigit():
```